# Magnetic declination in JavaScript / Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geospatial

In the context of a Google Map JavaScript application, what is the best way to get the magnetic declination for a certain Lat/Lon?

1. There seems to be no "easy" algorithm for that in JavaScript, or am I wrong?
2. Is there a way with Google Maps API to determine this, I haven't found one...
3. A Web Service which can be used. I have found [WebSites](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomagmodels/Declination.jsp) offering this, but no API.
4. Also see [here](http://www.geosats.com/webservice.html), there they use a JavaScript class for this (see comment)

Comment: There (http://www.geosats.com/contact.html -> WebService) they have implemented the http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomagmodels/Declination.jsp model in JavaScript. I'll ask them whether they are willing to share.

Comment: This one is the WMM port directly from the author, I found this one after Quentin has posted the other download: http://markmail.org/message/vaxt2pyuk5td5wa7

Comment: This script is valid for 2010-2014, and so as of 2015 it returns an error. There is an updated version of the script with 2015-2019 data here: http://www.geosats.com/js/WorldMagneticModel.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have shard this. For Google maps mashup with source see:-

http://www.bdcc.co.uk/Gmaps/Services.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is the same code as above and easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

There do appear to be web services supplied by ngdc.noaa.gov.

Have a look at the documentation - http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/calculators/declinationHelp

E.g.

http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/calculators/calculateDeclination?lat1=40&lon1=-105.25&resultFormat=xml

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example in Javascript/jQuery fetching magnetic declination for a certain lat/lon position from http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov.

```
declination=0;

function setdecl(v){
 console.log("declination found: "+v);
 declination=v;
}

function lookupMag(lat, lon) {
   var url=
"http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/calculators/calculateIgrfgrid?lat1="+lat+"&lat2="+lat+"&lon1="+lon+"&lon2="+lon+
"&latStepSize=0.1&lonStepSize=0.1&magneticComponent=d&resultFormat=xml";
   $.get(url, function(xml, status){
        setdecl( $(xml).find('declination').text());
   });
}

lookupMag(55.58552,12.1313);
```

For some reason they are using an internal redirect to a HTTP based server, so you cannot use this from a secure site like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbrams/vqvowpe7/1/), but this one worked on [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/tbrams/pen/pNErQE) a couple of hours ago.

Answer (score 2):

We recently had the same issue and developed a RESTful API to the World Magnetic Model. It wraps the original code for WMM2015v2, is open, and available here for anyone who needs it:

https://geomag.amentum.io